# PHP certain part of code is not executing

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hi I am facing a unique issue with my PHP script.Here is my code. After `writeToDB()` is executed I dont see the echo `("<script> top.location.href=www.facebook.com</script>");`

Can someone let me know why my script stops executing after writing to db?

```
<?php
function writeToDB($access_token,$uid,$username,$birthday,$gender,$age)
{
    /* Database Connection */
    $user = "xxxx";
    $password = "xxxx";
    $host = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 

    //connect to database, where tsnames.ora is setup
    $connect_obj = oci_connect($user, $password, $host);
    if ($connect_obj) {
        error_log("connected okay");
    } else {
        $err = OCIError();
        echo "Oracle connection error " . $err[text];
        return;
    }

    $select_query = "SELECT USER_ID FROM FBTABLE WHERE USER_ID= '$uid'";

    $select_sql_stmt = oci_parse($connect_obj, $select_query);
    //execute statement
    try {
        $r = oci_execute($select_sql_stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
        if (!$r) {
            $p = oci_error($select_sql_stmt);
            echo "Oci Execute error";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<br>Failed to get database info" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $user_id_in_db = null;
    while (oci_fetch($select_sql_stmt)) {
        $user_id_in_db = oci_result($select_sql_stmt, 'USER_ID');
    }

    // User already exists in db so update instead of insert
    if ($user_id_in_db != null) {
        $query ="UPDATE FBTABLE SET ACCESS_TOKEN='$access_token' WHERE USER_ID='$uid'";   
    } else {    
        $query = "INSERT INTO FBTABLE(ACCESS_TOKEN, USER_ID,USER_NAME,BIRTHDAY,GENDER,AGE)
                   VALUES
                   ('$access_token','$uid','$username','$birthday','$gender','$age')";
    }

        //create sql statement
    $sql_statement = oci_parse($connect_obj, $query);

    //execute statement
    try {
        $r = oci_execute($sql_statement, OCI_DEFAULT);
        if (!$r) {
            $p = oci_error($sql_statement);
            echo "Oci Execute error";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<br>Failed to get database info" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    //Commit transaction
    $committed = oci_commit($connect_obj);

    //Test whether commit was successful. If error occurred, return error message 
    if (!$committed) {
        $error = oci_error($conn);
        echo 'Commit failed. Oracle reports: ' . $error['message'];
    }

    //close the connection
    $oci_free_statement($sql_statement);

    if (oci_close($connect_obj)) {
        echo " oci connection not closed!!!";
    }

    //close the connection
    $oci_free_statement($sql_statement);
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
        $access_token = $_GET['access_token'];
        $uid          = $_GET['uid'];
        $username     = $_GET['username'];
        $birthday     = $_GET['birthday'];
        $gender       = $_GET['gender'];
        $age          = $_GET['age'];

        echo $username;
        writeToDB($access_token,$uid,$username,$birthday,$gender,$age);

        echo ("<script> top.location.href=www.facebook.com</script>");
    ?>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, maybe that command produces an error which terminates the script? What do the log files say? Also it might simply be that this function never returns - we cannot say since we don't know what that function does.

Comment: write contents of writeToDB function. It's certainly there where something happens.

Comment: are you sure no any error on `writeToDB` maybe error_display is off

Comment: What is in writeToDB()..?

Comment: Try commenting out the `writeToDb...` row. Probably the problem is there. Also, why using plain html (and without some PHP variables) with `echo`? Try to catch the error from `writeToDb`.

Comment: Is the output missing - or is your page just not redirecting? The latter is to be expected, because your JS code is wrong - unless you have a JS object by the name `www`, that has another object named `facebook`under it, and that again has `com` ... what you really want is `top.location.href="http://www.facebook.com/"` in that place. Please learn some JS _basics_ before proceeding.

Comment: I do not have access to the log files on the server, since this is a university server. I can see that writeToDB() writes the values to the DB successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think error is in `$oci_free_statement($sql_statement);` must be `oci_free_statement($sql_statement);` extra  `$` before  `oci_free_statement`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-free-statement.php

no any error show because of error_display is off

Comment: Thanks removing the extra $ worked. But now I get echo " oci connection not closed!!!"; message, though I am successfully redirecting.

Comment: see this example http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-close.php#example-2015 because Database connections are not closed until all references are closed

Comment: use `sleep(10);` for Time to Oracle for disconnecting

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript code should be

```
echo ("<script> top.location.href='http://www.facebook.com';</script>");
```

Comment: Thanks now I am able to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It's happen because writeToDB() causes error. You don't see this error because error_display is off or error_reporting = 0
Also maybe you didn't install OCI8. So when you call oci_connect it will cause error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are not using quotes around the string:
`www.facebook.com` should be `'www.facebook.com'`